# Canvas hover function in an image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How i can aplicate the hover function in image ? I am so nobbie in the world of canvas/Js i want to do a canvas game but i can't do the hover part, i tryed with elem.addEventListener,id, functions inside the card but i didn't resolve pls someone know how?

```
    var elem = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = elem.getContext("2d"),
    elemLeft = elem.offsetLeft,
    elemTop = elem.offsetTop,
    x1  = 0,
    x2  = 30,

    last = performance.now();
    let img = new Image();
    elem.addEventListener('click', function onClickCanvas(event) {
      console.log(
        "clientX: " + event.clientX +
        " - clientY: " + event.clientY);
        if (event.clientX >= 0
            && event.clientX <= 910
            && event.clientY >= 30
            && event.clientY <= 550 ) {
              alert("hit")}
    });
    elem.addEventListener('mouseover',function onMouuseoverCanvas(event){
      console.log(
        "clientXa: " + event.clientX +
        " - clientYa: " + event.clientY);
        if(event.clientX >= 0
            && event.clientX <= 910
            && event.clientY >= 30
            && event.clientY <= 550 ) {
              function ampliar(y){
                y.style.height = "20000px";}
            }

    });
    ctx.addId({id: 'hover'});ctx.onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
    ctx.addId({id: 'hover'});ctx.onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};

    function mouseOver() {
      ctx.addId({id: 'hover'});ctx.scale(0.6, 0.6);
    }

    function mouseOut() {
      ctx.addId({id: 'hover'});ctx.scale(0.6, 0.6);
    }
    img.onload = function() {
       ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.save();ctx.drawImage(img, x1, y);ctx.clip();ctx.addId({id: 'hover'});ctx.restore();
       ctx.save();ctx.drawImage(img, x2, y);ctx.clip();ctx.addId({id: 'hover'});ctx.restore();
```

Comment: where is `elem` defined?

Comment: its in the top i forget to pute in the code:

Comment: var elem = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = elem.getContext("2d"),
elemLeft = elem.offsetLeft,
elemTop = elem.offsetTop,